# Deriving an exact confidence interval for parameter of an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, confidence-interval, gamma-distribution

## Problem

Let $X \sim exp(\theta)$ and $X_1,..,X_n$ a random sample from $X$.
I've computed the MLE and the Fisher information number :
\begin{align*}
\theta_{MLE} &= \frac{1}{\bar{X}} \\
I(\theta) &= \frac{1}{\theta^2}
\end{align*}
I therefore obtain the following asymptotic distribution for $\lambda_{MLE} $ :
\begin{align}
    \sqrt{n} (\theta_{MLE} - \theta_0) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,\theta^2) 
\end{align}
However I now wish to derive an *exact* confidence interval for $\theta$.

## Attempt of solution

I know that :
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i &\sim Gamma(n,\theta)  \\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i &\sim Gamma(n,\theta/n)
\end{align}
So  an exact confidence interval for $\mu$ would be :
\begin{align}
    P_{\mu}\Big\{F^{-1}(\alpha/2)_{n,\theta/n} \leq \mu \leq F^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)_{n,\theta/n}\Big\} = 1-\alpha
\end{align}
Where $F^{-1}(\alpha/2)_{n,\theta/n}$ denotes the $\alpha/2$ quantile of a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $n$ and scale parameter $\theta/n$.
So knowing that if $X \sim Exp(\theta)$ :
\begin{align}
    \theta = 1/\mu 
\end{align}
I derive an *exact* confidence interval for the parameter $\theta$ of an exponential distribution :
\begin{align}
    P_{\theta}\Bigg\{\Big[F^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)_{n,\theta/n}\Big]^{-1}
    \leq \theta \leq
    \Big[F^{-1}(\alpha/2)_{n,\theta/n}\Big]^{-1} \Bigg\} = 1-\alpha
\end{align}
Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your work is correct for an exact, *equal-tailed* confidence interval; that is, the probability that the interval exceeds the true parameter equals $\alpha/2$, which is also the probability the interval is below the true parameter.  One could construct an interval that does not allocate the total error $\alpha$ equally, but still has the same coverage probability $1 - \alpha$.

An alternate formulation of the lower and upper confidence limit can be obtained by noting that the distribution of $1/\bar X$ is *inverse gamma* with PDF
$$f_{\theta_{\text{MLE}}} (s) = \frac{(n \theta/s)^n e^{-n \theta/s}}{s  \Gamma(n)}, \quad s > 0.$$  Thus the lower and upper limits may be expressed directly in terms of quantiles of this distribution, namely
$$\Pr\left[F_{\theta_{\text{MLE}}}^{-1}(\alpha/2) \le \theta \le F_{\theta_{\text{MLE}}}^{-1}(1 - \alpha/2)\right] = 1 - \alpha.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.